# Euclidean Geometry Question 1

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

$|FE| = 7 cm$

$|AB| = 2 cm$

OAEF is a rectangle. ABCD is a square.

O is the center of the quarter circle.

$|ED| = x =?$

Comment: (1) Numerically find $OC^2$; (2) Symbolically, in terms of $x$, find $OE^2$; (3) $OE^2=OC^2$. Why?; (4) Solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $OC,OE $ are radii of circle

By Pythagoras Theorem

$$(OB)^2+(BC)^2=r^2$$ where $r$ is radius of circle
SO,
$$r=\sqrt{85}$$

Similarly,
$$(OF)^2+(FE)^2=r^2$$

$$(x+2)^2+49=r^2$$

which gives $x=4$